# StackOverflow продан за $1.8 млрд

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, stackoverflow

Собственно новость:

https://techcrunch.com/2021/06/02/stack-overflow-acquired-by-prosus-for-a-reported-1-8-billion/

Что изменится в компании после продажи? Как это затронет SO на русском?

Можно ли верить тому, что сказано в конце статьи?

> Today we’re pleased to announce that Stack Overflow is joining Prosus. Prosus is an investment and holding company, which means that the most important part of this announcement is that Stack Overflow will continue to operate independently, with the exact same team in place that has been operating it, according to the exact same plan and the exact same business practices. Don’t expect to see major changes or awkward “synergies”. The business of Stack Overflow will continue to focus on Reach and Relevance, and Stack Overflow for Teams. The entire company is staying in place: we just have different owners now.

Comment: _Можно ли верить_, нельзя верить, новая метла всегда метёт по новому.

Comment: Меня больше интересует, почему об этом мы узнаём не из предварительного обсуждения и не от менеджера комьюнити, а от участника, который узнал об этом в прессе. Выводы пусть каждый делает сам.

Comment: Таки где я могу получить свою долю?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov уже поделили всё `lets Stack Overflow continue as an independent site -- and also mints 61 new millionaires.` Вот интересно, эти все новые, 61  миллионеры, сотрудники компании или только руководство? Или это коммерческая тайна и задавать такие вопросы неприлично?

Comment: @VladD вообще был [пост в блоге](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/), но кто ж его читает)

Comment: Откуда капитализация? Здесь даже рекламы нет

Comment: @ВоваХолод тут есть реклама :)

Comment: Гм, любопытная идея: [Скорее всего сделают пейволл, как на thetimes.co.uk каком-нибудь — «вы видите 40% ответа, чтобы увидеть остальное оформите подписку».](https://habr.com/en/news/t/560756/#comment_23109842) (Интересно, а если 10к репы - то дадут без пейволла почитать? А свои же ответы?)

Comment: @AK пейволл выглядит бессмысленным, Creative Commons позволит поднять легальное зеркало без пейволла

Comment: Когда SO начиналось, его конкурентом был <s>сайт по экспертной смене пола</s> expertsexchange.com, на нём был paywall, из-за чего они не выдержали конкуренции с SO.

Comment: Вот что бывает, когда на сайте плохо проработана функция поиска, они там в Prosus наверно задолбались гуглить, и решили купить SO и сразу делать запрос SQL. Только не учли, что есть SEDE. XD

Comment: Наймут больше [южно-африканских программистов.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naspers)

Comment: Т.к. у каждых людей свое видение, то как минимум что нть да поменяется.

Answer (score 12):

К сожалению или к счастью в сообществе владельцев больших компаний чаще решают деньги. Я бы сказал, что это даже не крупная сделка, а так, средняя. Но меня определенно радует, что SO хотя-бы столько стоит.

> Что изменится в компании после продажи?

Душить SE после покупки, "наводить порядок" в менеджменте - кому это надо? Вот если бы у SO было все плохо в части бизнеса, тогда бы может и пошумели изменениями. А пока самое масштабное изменение, которое я вижу - смена шрифтов. Ничего такого, чего нельзя было ожидать до продажи, не стоит ожидать и после.

Но на этот вопрос правильно сможет ответить только тот, кто хорошо знает покупателя.

> Как это затронет SO на русском?

Если SO закроют, то это наверное затронет и SO на русском, но я не вижу предпосылок.

> Можно ли верить тому, что сказано в конце статьи?

Я думаю, да. Во всяком случае нет причин не верить. Во всяком случае в краткосрочной перспективе.

**UPD:** пост в SO блоге [Prosus’s Acquisition of Stack Overflow: Our Exciting Next Chapter](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/)

Comment: Насколько я знаю, многие компании длительное время является убыточными. Например, тот же ВКонтакте долгое время был убыточным и существовал на деньги инвесторов (не знаю, прибыльный ли он сейчас). Интересно, прибылен ли StackOverflow? У компаний есть период раскрутки, когда они работают в минус, причём этот период может длиться несколько лет. Даже тот же телеграмм вроде бы до сих пор уходит в минус. Так вот вопрос в том, убыточен ли стековерфлоу? И если да - то как и когда его будут монетизировать?

Comment: Я не так хорошо знаю стек, но вроде бы единственные точки монетизации - это вакансии (которые я видел только на англоязычном стеке) и реклама (которой вроде бы по факту и нет, поправьте, если я ошибаюсь). Если мои наблюдения верны, то с большой долей вероятности стек убыточен (сомневаюсь, что на одних вакансиях можно поддерживать такую значительную инфраструктуру), а если он убыточен, то рано или поздно произойдёт монетизация.

Comment: @Zhenyria SE имеет фичу Q&A движка для корпоративных пользователей, и насколько мне известно она востребована и вроде-как успешно монетизируется.

Comment: Англоязычный SO конечно будет жить. А вот русскоязычный (также как португальский и японский) вполне могут прикрыть. И прочие мелкие разделы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov время пилить свой ruSO?

Comment: @Дмитрий, он уже был, но из-за отсутствия финансирования откочевал. У вас деньги есть?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov есть, а сколько надо? Я не смыслю в финансах)

Comment: @Дмитрий $1,8kkk

Comment: @aepot, это явно перебор, imho за $1M ежегодно можно было бы взяться (но у меня нет подходов к таким меценатам)

Comment: @avp $1M ежегодно - это очень мало.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, для ruSO (в формате бывшего hashcode) мало? Я бы ввязался, если у вас есть гарантированное финансирование черным налом лет, скажем, на 5.

Answer (score 12):

За свою трудовую карьеру компании в которых я работал продавали 2 раза. Сейчас кстати, в компании которую продали и мы находимся в состоянии процесса "интеграции" :)

Для персонала процесс купли-продажи в большинстве своем ничего не означает, особенно для линейного персонала. С топами, да возникают проблемы, как правило они идут под нож, некоторые конечно выживают, но по моим наблюдениям не более 10-20%.

Проблемы могут у SO могут возникнуть если новые собственники имеют собственное, отличное от предыдущих собственников видение бизнеса. В данном случае, новый собственник [Prosus](https://www.reuters.com/companies/PRXJn.J) не является просто спекулятивным или институциональным инвестором, а компанией с приличным опытом в Интернет торговле финтехе и прочих плюшках, соответственно, полагаю, что у них есть собственное видение о будущем SO. Так что, [Хьюстон, у нас проблема](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD,_%D1%83_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B).

Ждем изменений, которые по моему личному мнению безусловно, давно уже назрели. SO и в частности ruSO уже в кризисе несколько лет как.

Comment: Не знаю, что насчет проблем Хьюстона, но CEO в блоге пишет об обратном.

Comment: @aepot Обещать, - не значит жениться

Comment: @aepot у CEO работа такая всем обещать, что все будет ок, они всегда обещают/декларируют :)

Comment: @aepot мне вспоминается скриншот как сео-работник в передрелизный день Киберпанка говорил что очередного переноса релиза точно не будет. А на следующий день он был) Не думаю что кто-то отчитывается перед СЕО работниками. А если кто и отчитывается, то не думаю что ему можно разглашать всю информацию. Все что говорит СЕО можно смело пропускать через фильтр

Comment: @Andrew вы путаете Search Engine Optimization (SEO) и Chief Executive Office (CEO), конечно seo работник никто и звать его никак, а CEO - это все таки ж фигура...

Comment: "За свою трудовую карьеру компании в которых я работал продавали 2 раза." - Это на каком языке написано?

Answer (score 8):

Довольно занятно сейчас смотреть на то, что происходило прошлые годы, а также на заявления нового CEO и менеджеров SE. Продажа планировалась давно. Изменения будут. Ждите с 2022. Пока что просто подготавливаются.

Предполагаю, что компания будет всё сильнее уходить в корпоративный сегмент, что, очевидно, негативно скажется на сообществе.

Comment: Вы ясновидищий?

Comment: @Зонтик возможно (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 6):

Полагаю, что ни для кого не новость, что некоторые (если не сказать многие) хедхантеры частенько ищут кандидатов тут или на гитхабе. На технических специалистов всегда дефицит, поэтому думаю двигаться будут в эту сторону, задел под это есть уже давно (developer story и тп). Может это и хорошо, может это будет стимулировать какое-то положительное движение в плане наполняемости хорошим контентом, потому что сейчас многие энтузиасты уже не испытывают энтузиазма.

Рекламная же модель, очевидно, не будет работать, потому что никто не захочет её смотреть и будут отключать в настройках, а если такую возможность уберут - то по-старинке, адблокерами.

---

Вообще, конечно, с точки зрения пользователей, внёсших значительный вклад в базу ответов/вопросов, обидно получается. Особенно с точки зрения модераторов. Вроде как провозглашается "коммьюнити" и всякое такое "возвышенное", а с другой стороны - зарабатывают на этом только идеологи, но никак не исполнители. О чём я, собственно, давно уже говорил. Кажется с монетизацией репы и модераторства пора что-то делать.

Comment: Монетизация репы в серьезных масштабах автоматом означает paywall на ответах.

Comment: @PashaPash раскройте мысль, пожалуйста? При какой модели монетизации?

Comment: монетизация репутации означает что нужен стабильный источник доходов, который рос бы с ростом этой самой репутации. реклама не подходит (адблокеры среди девелоперов слишком распространены, да и потенциальные рекламные темы ограничены, это ж не гугл, где ищут всё). единственное место, где компания может собирать деньги пропорционально репутации пользователя - это ответы этого самого пользователя. соответственно, если хотите получать деньги за репутацию - то просмотр ответов придется делать платным.

Comment: из вариантов еще - денежные конкурсы (вместо репутации) - но это капля в море. тут и просто репутации на конкурсы народ жалеет, что уже говорить про деньги. может быть еще схема со спонсорами, как на гитхабе, сработала бы - но никто не мешает вам и сейчас повесить в профиле PayPal Tip Jar

Comment: @PashaPash у меня немного иное представление. Компания продолжает так же зарабатывать, но делится с пользователем доходами пропорционально репе. Платный просмотр ответов не зайдёт точно, всегда можно уйти на реддит или даже тостер, если говорить про русский сегмент.

Comment: "так же зарабатывать" - вы исходите из того, что (1) компания реально прибыльна (а не развивается за счет инвестиций, (2) у компании есть довольно большая **лишняя** прибыль, которую компания почему-то должна потратить не на рост и развитие, а решит раздать в качестве мотивационных выплат (при том, что деньги дают только краткосрочную мотивацию, потом она падает до бейзлайна, и даже ниже), (3) пользователи ruSO при этом составляют сколь-либо значительную долю участников с высокой репутацией. По мне - так все три предположения ложны.

Comment: Ну и при текущем плане монетизации (через приватные команды) - кросс финансирование вида "возьмем деньги у энтерпрайза на развитие продукта teams и спустим их на краткосрочную мотивацию не-энтерпрайз части пропорционально наркучиваемым циферкам" - звучит как очень плохое бизнес решение :)

Comment: ну я не говорил про монетизацию русского сегмента именно, да и вообще это не имеет значения. смысл в том, что не поощряя авторов ответов (авторы вопросов и так поощряются ответами) можно прийти в тупик, на одной идее далеко не уедешь. сейчас мы наблюдаем кризис от того, что ожидания пользователей не оправданы. иллюзия самоуправления была развеяна, время новой идеологии. относительно прибыльна/не прибыльна тоже не так важно, если привлекаются инвестиции (внутренние или внешние), то они должны тратиться на выплаты авторам, это такая же статья, как и, например, разработка ибо без контента нет СО

Comment: тратить инвестиции на решение кризиса "компания сделала не так, как мы хотели, а раньше делала так, мы думали тут демократия, а тут не демократия" на неосновном сайте вместо реального развития продукта - это выбрасывание денег на ветер. Особенно для сайта, где сообщество явно идет против основного показателя (количества вопросов == покрытие в выдаче), да еще и мотает репутацию "соревнованиями". Инвестиции всегда даются на развитие. Выплаты людям, которые и так отвечают бесплатно - это не развитие, это деньги на ветер.

Comment: ну и опять же, привязать выплаты к репутации? так ее будут мотать (и сейчас мотают, и модераторы особо ничего с этим не могут поделать). Будут отвечать на все. Будут гребсти даже домашки - десятка репы не лишняя!. Очередь закрытия встанет. Мы тут все ждем, пока количество перерастет в качество - а останется тупо количество :)

Comment: реклама - тоже выбрасывание денег на ветер, с таким подходом. если взять "монетизацию репы" как гипотезу решения (а это так и есть, потому что это пока не опровергнуто и не доказано), то трата денег на это вполне оправдана. и не на такое тратят. но вообще мне безразлично на самом деле, пусть делают, что хотят, всё равно нас не спросят :) что меня на самом деле беспокоит, точнее возмущает, так это эксплуатация сообщества в корыстных интересах. понимание этого в принципе даёт понимание и того, что никто не собирается с нами ничем делиться добровольно

Comment: к слову, корпораты как и зачем используют СО? им движок продают? зачем это корпорациям, неужели нет внутренних вики/чатов тематических?

Comment: SO for Teams - https://stackoverflow.com/teams - приватные SO - это текущий путь монетизации. бесплатные до 50 юзеров, кстати. компании создают хостинг для контента, юзеры сами наполняют, сами же бесплатно эксплуатируют труд других (копипастят, а зарплату получают!). гитхаб, реддит, и все в современном интернете работает по этой схеме. а если ожидаете оплаты за потребляемый контент - будьте готовы за этот контент платить (как на expertsexchange, кстати, давно его не видно). схема "отнять у буржуев и поделить" - не работает. не хотите создавать контент бесплатно - не создавайте, всего делов.

Comment: ну или будьте готовы получать пропорционально заработанному компанией напрямую на контенте (как на хабре). в случае ruSO - это 0/количество юзеров. что примерно 0 :)

Comment: как работает teams я понимаю, я не очень понимаю - кому это надо? зачем? мне всё же кажется, что рекрутинговое направление более перспективно, хотя статистику не знаю

Answer (score 3):

Я считаю, что ничего плохого c SO не случится. Если случится - из неоткуда появится такой же сайт с аналогичным функционалом. А то что сменился собственник - это даже хорошо, потому что он захочет развивать проект, тогда как старый собственник уже давно забил болт.

Развивать есть куда, можно подключить монетизацию к ответам. Можно прямо здесь организовать челенджи с задачками и соревнованиями типа спортивного программирования. Можно подключить зум, дабы главные специалисты по ответам проводили платные или бесплатные конференции.

Comment: Старый развивает в сторону teams. Для спортивного программирования есть https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. А монетизация к ответам - это прямой путь к expertsexchange.com, который как раз и умер из-за появления SO