# Когда, по вашим прикидкам, ruSO умрёт окончательно?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow, нытьё

Я в последние полгода стал замечать при поиске дубликатов, что гугл перестал выдавать ответы с ru.so на первой странице. И совсем перестал показывать плашку "другие ответы с этого сайта".

Это очень раздражает само по себе, из-за того что приходится вбивать site: руками, но больше всего наводит на невесёлые мысли. Гугль уже записал этот сайт в аутсайдеры, и это процесс с положительной обратной связью - чем глубже всякие coderoad спихивают сайт в поисковой выдаче, тем меньше на нем трафика, тем ниже гуголь опускает в выдаче.

Этот процесс, среди прочего, наглядно показывает, что выбранная стратегия "Облизать каждого недотёпу, решившего задать вопрос, и наплевать на поисковую ценность ответа" и "Дать трибуну каждому недоучке" не работает.

Я понимаю что эти очевидные выводы - лишь никому не интересное сотрясение воздуха, поэтому задам практический вопрос - через сколько, по вашим прикидкам, сайт окончательно загнётся? Мой прогноз - 5 лет.

Comment: Какая польза сообществу предполагается от этого вопроса и ответов на него? Прост интересно в контексте текста про стратегии _«Облизать каждого недотёпу»_ и _«Дать трибуну каждому недоучке»_.

Comment: Хм. У меня, например, в настройках Гугла стоит английский язык: в результате ru.so отсекается. Кроме того, почти всегда я сам ввожу поисковый запрос на английском. Неудивительно, что ru.so опять в пролёте. Когда-то раньше я искал на русском. Но время шло, я осваивал English, я искал всё более сложные темы (шанс ответа на которые намного выше на английском) - может и у вас такая же ситуация?

Comment: @yar85 а [кто-то ещё ждёт пользы сообществу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11037/179379) от вопросов на мете? %)

Comment: @Ипатьев, в случае конкретно этого вопроса, отдельно взятого, может подразумеваться какая-то польза: потому что если понимать текст вопроса буквально, он называет причиной ухудшения ситуации плохие вопросы и ответы (от "недотеп" и "недоучек", соотв.) - вот я и уточняю этот момент... подразумевается ли польза от этого вопроса, и если да, то какая именно. Если переформулировать, уточняю "чем этот вопрос отличается от тех которые он критикует", чтобы лучше понимать цель и смысл вопроса + ответов на него.

Comment: Да нет. Это очередной крик души, после того как я увидел очередной вопрос, который не закрыл вовремя дублем, и в который успело набижать племя младое, гиперактивное.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь намного понятнее какое обсуждение тут предполагается (полученное пояснение уберегло от "слишком серьезного" ответа про полноту замещения [ru]SO в плане функционала).

Comment: Когда [новый владелец](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11558) осознает, что ruSO для него бесполезен, тогда и умрёт

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov язык запроса очень опосредованно влияет на выдачу. Мне часто в первых строках выдачи даются результаты хоть и нужные, но на другом языке. Т.е. ищу, например, на русском, я получаю ссылки на английскую википедию.

Comment: @Ипатьев, да вы, батенька, оптимист

Comment: А мне вот что интересно - а не окончательно загнётся, то это тогда как? По всей видимости, автору вопроса стало просто скучно (к такому выводу я пришел, имхо).

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/Русский-so-умирает

Comment: @Sevastopol' каждый год умирает)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я бы сказал не `каждый год`, а `с каждым годом`. Я вот полгода сюда не заглядывал, сегодня заглянул -- на странице с вопросами по `Java` за пять дней примерно 70 вопросов, большинство из них явно указывает на то, что автор вопроса никогда не читал справку на тему "Как задать хороший вопрос", и подавляющее большинство остаются без ответа, хотя вопросы элементарные.  Ну еще полгода не буду заглядывать. Я знаю, что никто не заплачет, но мне жалко -- хороший был ресурс, но политика, главным приоритетом которой является популярность, ведет к деградации и к смерти ресурса.

Answer (score 6):

Учитывая относительную текучку участников-ответчиков, отсутствие у ruSO собственных перспектив (в отрыве от enSO), укрепление тенденции к заполнению невопросами (по субъективной оценке наиболее популярной метки `[js]`) - можно сделать вывод что ruSO **уже** благополучно загнулся. Как минимум в плане достижения его официальной цели (база знаний).

Конечно, будь у ruSO прочные топовые позиции в выдаче поисковиков, посетителей и контента было бы больше (а значит и больше активистов).
И все же, закрытие ruSO как проекта, вряд ли произойдет в ближайшие 5 лет. Думаю что этот срок стоит как минимум удвоить: просто из-за того что первичная маркетинговая цель этого сайта заключается имхо в вирусной рекламе SE (а не в прямых приводах юзеров на ее основные площадки)... и значит, ранжирование поисковиками не особо-то должно волновать владельцев, пока сохраняется посещаемость от людей с вопросами, и пока брэнд SO узнаваем в рунете. Качество вопросов и ответов с такой точки зрения не имеет значения, а люди которые несут сюда "сделайте мне"/"подумайте за меня" вряд ли куда-то исчезнут за 5 лет. Идти им (в рунете) по сути больше некуда, кроме как сюда. Ведь на codroad домашку не сделают, за ручку по теории не поводят, и не выслушают терпеливо все их капризные "мне нужно" :)

Вот вероятность появления жизнеспособного конкурирующего проекта (где можно задавать вопросы и не быть затролленым) в течение 10+ следующих лет, видится вполне реальной. Такие сайтики же создаются регулярно, просто не выживают... но чем больше такого печального опыта знает рунет, тем выше вероятность что у кого-то в итоге получится его учесть, обойдя уже известные ошибки предшественников, и набрав популярность (а так как процесс набора популярности небыстрый, такой вот прогноз по срокам).

Comment: Тогда я пошёл. enSO будет полезнее для меня конкретно. Меня тоже удивляет не желание развивать как базу знаний, большинство набрасывается на простенькие вопросы, чтобы рейтингу поднабить. Да, что греха таить я тоже начал:) теоретические вопросы с новинками не интересны, переводы и ассоциации, как я посмотрю тоже. Посмотрел react-native свободное для вопросов-ответов. Тоже никому нет интереса. Печально. Олд скул тоже не особо поддерживает начинания. Я попробовал найти ключик к ruSO. Не удалось;)

Comment: @Dmitry, _«Тогда я пошёл. enSO будет полезнее для меня конкретно»_ - понимаю... я бы тоже на основу мигрировал, но не изъясняюсь по-английски (только читать могу, что и делаю: в работе, поиск юзаю именно на enSO, а не местный). На основе конечно тоже не радуга и единороги, но интересного и полезного контента там субъективно в разы больше. _«большинство набрасывается на простенькие вопросы, чтобы рейтингу поднабить»_ - имхо, это скорее от желания порешать задачки или помочь с проблемой, а не рейтинга ради. Хотя у каждого своя мотивация.

Comment: *это скорее от желания порешать задачки или помочь с проблемой, а не рейтинга ради*, да у меня сложилось по другому. Легкий вопрос => короткий ответ => рейтинг в копилку. Вопрос может быть дубликатом и темой размусоленной со всех сторон тысячный раз. *но не изъясняюсь по-английски* - может повод начать?;)

Comment: @Dmitry, _«Вопрос может быть дубликатом и темой размусоленной со всех сторон тысячный раз»_ - когда успешно закрывают дубликатом, ответы с полученным рейтингом становятся не так уж важны. То есть, если такие вопросы занимают отвечающих за рейтинг, то это по идее как раз очень хорошо (короткие ответы осядут пылью истории, пока Дух до нее не доберется удалив самые непопулярные вопросы). _«может повод начать?;)»_ - пробовал многократно, но не дается мне инглиш никак (особенно времена и формы глаголов убивают, мозгов на них не хватает).

Comment: Не могу не согласиться, всё так. Вполне реальная картина.

Answer (score 4):

У вас же доступ к аналитике есть. Даже если в выдаче не на 1 странице, то трафик, судя по всему, не особо пострадал от этого.

[image: Трафик]

А вот количество ответов и голосов падает.

[image: Ответа/голоса]

| Месяц | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Июнь | 1550 | 1350 |
| Июль | 1500 | 1450 |
| Сентябрь | 1600 | 1400 |
| Октябрь | 1700 | 1450 |

Количество вопросов, что интересно, тоже падает.

Если так продолжится, то через через несколько лет упадёт настолько, что сайтом перестанут заниматься, отвечающие окончательно уйдут, и ruSO превратится просто в архив.

Comment: .zip, .rar, .ruso

Comment: Сезонная активность учтена? Учитывается эффект автоматического удаления старых вопросов?

Comment: @Kromster сезонность есть, но я сравниваю показатели за конкретные месяцы. На графика за последний год-два можно потыкать в метрики по месяцам. Видно, что падает в целом.

Comment: Политика администрации направлена на рост популярности. Но погоня за популярностью в ущерб качеству -- занятие контрпродуктивное. Падает качество -- падает интерес к сайту, падает интерес -- падает количество вопросов и ответов. Это видно даже на цифрах, но если оценивать не только количество, но и качество и вопросов и ответов, то картина будет еще более печальной.